# Fast and/or save way to save NSManagedObjectContext on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, save, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am creating an app for displaying Cora Data objects. The app should not create or delete entities but I want to give the user the opportunity to add a entity to their favorites. To do so, I added a boolean "isFavorite" attribute. When the users adds a entity, I update it like so:

```
[_currentObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isFavorite"];
[_managedObjectContext refreshObject:_currentObject mergeChanges:YES];
```

When the app closes, I save the context like so:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
     [self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
    NSLog(@"save done...");
}
```

That work good but the problem is, that it takes about 10 seconds to complete the save. When the user presses the home button and then closes the app (with double click on homebutton) the context won't be completely saved.

Is there a faster (or save) methords to save the context? I don't need to save the hole file again, just the objects that have been changed...

My file is binary and about 5 MB of size and it will increase as more data will be added.

Comment: You could try to migrate to a SQL store. Perfomances are better.

Comment: I've tried that, but it seems that some of my complex relationships are not working with SQL store type...

Comment: What do you mean? Could you provide some details? Binary or SQL stores are the same from a high-level point of view.